# query same column for two different output

Tags: sql, hive

My table in hive:

```
liked                   string                                      
user_id                 int                                         
video_end_type          int                                         
minutes_played          int                                         
video_id                int                                         
geo_cd                  string                                      
channel_id              int                                         
creator_id              int                                         
time                    timestamp                                   
disliked                string
```

Query:  Determine the total duration of videos played by each type of user, where the type of user can be 'subscribed' or 'unsubscribed.' An unsubscribed user is the one whose video is either not present in the lookup table created from the dataset - user-subscn.txt or has
subscription_end_date earlier than the timestamp of the video played by him.

Lookup Table: user-subscn

```
user_id                 int                                         
start_date              bigint                                      
end_date                bigint
```

Output:  It should include the columns – user type, duration.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  How many tables do you have?  It is not even clear in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```
select (case when us.user_id is not null then 'Subscribed' else 'Not Subscribed' end) as which,
       sum(minutes_played)
from t left join
     user_subscn us
     on t.user_d = us.user_id and
        t.time between us.start_date and us.end_date
group by which;
```

Comment: I think query requires data to be in format:

Type of user(subscribed or unsubscribed)   Total number of video minutes by this user

Comment: So, instead of count(*) can I just write minutes_played?

Comment: @AekanshGupta . . . Yes.  I missed that nuance in the question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I think this will help a lot.